# How to enumarte through dictionary values from two keys and output the values in txt file using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, dictionary, txt

My data looks like below, and it is in excel file with extension xlsx, so I am using `openpyxl` library to read the file in python and extract the data from row 6 onwards for 2 columns,and I am appending the extracted data into dictionary with keys "Column_name" and "Column_Type". The reason for doing this way is because, I would like to add extra string between the extracted data. The string I would like to add is CREATE TABLE TRANSIENT TABLE STG_EMPLOYEE();

So far my code and output looks like below.My expected output in txt file is also mentioned below. If you notice, I would like to enumerate value from both keys at same time, I am not sure how to achive this in `python` so any help is appreciated ?

Thanks in advance for your time and effort!

**Data**

```
File Name:  Employee
Sheet Name: Employee
File Type:  csv
    
Field Name  Type
Name    String
Salary  Numeric
Date    Date
Phone   Int
```

**Code so far**

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

data_file='\\test.xlsx'

# Load the entire workbook.
wb = load_workbook(data_file)
ws = wb['Employee'] #Access Sheet


outputFile = open('/output.txt', 'w')  # Text file Output
outputFile.write("CREATE TABLE TRANSIENT TABLE STG_EMPLOYEE({});".format(theString) + "\n")

mylines={"Column_name":[],"Column_Type":[]} #Getting 2 columns data from row 6

for i in range(6, ws.max_row+1):  
        name = ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value
        name1=ws.cell(row=i, column=2).value
        mylines["Column_name"].append(name) #Appending dictionary key "Column_name"
        mylines["Column_Type"].append(name1) #Appending dictionay key "Column_type"
        
theString = " "
# This relies on the lists 'Column_name' and 'Column_Type' always being the same length
# I.e., there should always be a value for each key
for i in range(len(mylines['Column_name'])):
    theString += mylines['Column_name'][i] + " " + mylines['Column_Type'][i]
    if i < ws.max_row:
        theString += ", "       


outputFile.close()
```

**Output in txt file with above Code:**

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSIENT TABLE STG_EMPLOYEE([['Name', 'Salary', 'Date', 'Phone'], ['String', 'Numeric', 'Date', 'Int']]);
```

**Expected output in Txt file**

```
   CREATE TABLE TRANSIENT TABLE STG_EMPLOYEE( Name String, Salary Numeric, Date Date, Phone Int);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take advantage of the fact that there should always be the same number of items in the `"Column_name"` and `"Column_Type"` lists to reduce the problem to iteration using a single variable:

```
# Simulated Excel Data
ws = {
    'max_row': 3,
    'cell': [
    ['Name', 'String'],
    ['Salary', 'Numeric'],
    ['Date', 'Date'],
    ['Phone', 'Int']
    ]
}

mylines={"Column_name":[],"Column_Type":[]}

for i in range(0, ws['max_row']+1):  
    name = ws['cell'][i][0]
    name1=ws['cell'][i][1]
    mylines["Column_name"].append(name)
    mylines["Column_Type"].append(name1)

theString = " "
# This relies on the lists 'Column_name' and 'Column_Type' always being the same length
# I.e., there should always be a value for each key
for i in range(len(mylines['Column_name'])):
    theString += mylines['Column_name'][i] + " " + mylines['Column_Type'][i]
    if i < ws['max_row']:
        theString += ", "

# OLD
print("CREATE TABLE TRANSIENT TABLE STG_EMPLOYEE({});".format([(mylines[k]) for k,v in mylines.items()]) + "\n")
# NEW
print("CREATE TABLE TRANSIENT TABLE STG_EMPLOYEE({});".format(theString) + "\n")
```

When I ran this, I got the following output (the first line from the old version and the second line from the new version):

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSIENT TABLE STG_EMPLOYEE([['Name', 'Salary', 'Date', 'Phone'], ['String', 'Numeric', 'Date', 'Int']]);

CREATE TABLE TRANSIENT TABLE STG_EMPLOYEE( Name String, Salary Numeric, Date Date, Phone Int);
```

Of course, if you have actual numeric and other non-string data in your spreadsheet, you'll also want to cast the variable values to strings using `str()` before appending them to `theString`.

The only difference from your code (other than the changes I made to have the code work as a standalone without an actual spreadsheet) is replacing the `format` parameter in the last line with a string built by appending the values from both lists in `mylines`.

Comment: Thank you! Now the only issue I am facing is there seems to be comma at the end of the string i.e. Phone Int, which I don't want. Any way to get rid of that one ?

Comment: I'm not sure what would be causing that, as I didn't have a comma at the end when I ran the code in the answer.  My best guess is that it has to do with the condition in the if statement not evaluating to `False` when expected.  The if statement is supposed to detect the last iteration with `i < ws['max_row']` and only add a comma every time *except* the last iteration.

Comment: Did you have to change the syntax or condition in the if statement to accommodate your Excel sheet data?  What does it look like as you're currently using it in your program?

Comment: Updated my code...sorry when I restarted the NB. I received "NameError: name 'theString' is not defined" at outputFile.write("CREATE TABLE TRANSIENT TABLE STG_EMPLOYEE({});".format(theString) + "\n")

Comment: Maybe try moving the lines `outputFile = open('/output.txt', 'w')  # Text file Output`
`outputFile.write("CREATE TABLE TRANSIENT TABLE STG_EMPLOYEE({});".format(theString) + "\n")` to the end of the program, right before `outputFile.close()`?

Comment: The error is because your 'write to output file' line has a reference to `theString` before `theString` is initialized.  It seems like moving this statement to after the final for loop should fix this.

Comment: That error is fixed. Thank you! Still having an issue with comma

Comment: While I don't know why this is occurring, here is a simple workaround to fix it: `string1 = "abc def ghi,"`
`string2 = string1[:len(string1) - 1]`
`print(string2)` just take the string that has a comma at the end and slice it to remove the last character.  Then use the new string inside your `format` statement.

Comment: Thank you! something is wrong with my environment or something else..will figure out. Thanks a lot for your help!